# How can I mimic fixed positioning for horizontal scrolling but maintain normal vertical scrolling? (Sticky column for a table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

Let me start off by saying I can't believe how much trouble I've been having with this. I've tried next to everything with no luck. And unfortunately I have a lot of requirements that I need to meet and cannot make a lot of concessions.

Basically, I need to make a sortable table whose first column acts as a "sticky" column. All other columns can scroll horizontally and "into" the first column.

Now, that's *sort of* simple enough. However, the problem with fixed positioning on the first column is that it does not respect the bounds of the 1200x600px container that it is in. But more importantly, applying a fixed positioning makes it difficult for that first column to scroll along with the rest of the text.

An example:

[image]

Now, as you may imagine, when you scroll you get this:
[image]

Which, in essence, defeats the entire purpose of having a sticky column in the first place.

All I want to be able to do is have everything exactly the way it is now, but also to "bind" the scroll onto the fixed column so it scrolls along with the rest of the table.

However, a few things to take into consideration:

- The headers of the table need to stay where they are (i.e. can't just put everything into another div and scroll it. Not sure that would work with fixed positioning anyway).
- Everything needs to be sortable, so by taking two tables and jamming them together (as I've seen in other answers) we complicate that and future endeavors that require the left and right maintain some semblance of association.

Can't even tell you how much I'd appreciate some resolution here. I've been working on this for a week. I've tried every JS library under the sun but the issue with them is that most of those libraries follow a convention of creating multiple tables and hiding some on the page. This introduces a lot of lag when scrolling (especially with large amounts of data). It would be ideal if we could somehow find a way to do this with minimal hackery, although at this point I'll try anything.

The good news is we can always rely on a fixed with and fixed height for each of the table cells.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ErcanPeker Thanks for the response! Sadly that doesn't seem to do it for me. The issue becomes the headers not sticking to the top of the container. Also it seems once `position: absolute` is applied, the first column does not overflow within the container it's in (in this case, the wrapper div), it just pokes out of the wrapper as if it's not even there. E.g. https://i.imgur.com/2CoOPgC.png

Answer (score 0):

hi ActiveModel The first table colomn is sticky in the bellow page

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .table-scroll {
            position: relative;
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

        .table-wrap {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .table-scroll table {
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        .table-scroll th, .table-scroll td {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            background: #fff;
            white-space: nowrap;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .table-scroll thead, .table-scroll tfoot {
            background: #f9f9f9;
        }

        .clone {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

            .clone th, .clone td {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            .clone td, .clone th {
                border-color: transparent
            }

            .clone tbody th {
                visibility: visible;
                color: red;
            }

            .clone .fixed-side {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                background: #eee;
                visibility: visible;
            }

            .clone thead, .clone tfoot {
                background: transparent;
            }
    </style>
 </head >

<body>
    <div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
        <div class="table-wrap">
            <table class="main-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="fixed-side" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
                        <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
                        <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
                        <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
                        <th scope="col">Header 6</th>
                        <th scope="col">Header 7</th>
                        <th scope="col">Header 8</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
                        <td>
                            Cell content<br>
                            test
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content longer</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content longer</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content longer</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content longer</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content longer</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                        <td>Cell content</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="fixed-side">&nbsp;</th>
                        <td>Footer 2</td>
                        <td>Footer 3</td>
                        <td>Footer 4</td>
                        <td>Footer 5</td>
                        <td>Footer 6</td>
                        <td>Footer 7</td>
                        <td>Footer 8</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>See <a href="https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/LBrMxa" target="blank">position Sticky version </a>with no JS</p>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       jQuery(document).ready(function () {
           jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');
       });
   </script>
</body>
 </html >
```

Comment: Hey @LDS, thanks for the response. Sadly the same two issues persist, which is that 1.) the headers are not sticky and 2.) with this sort of approach, being able to sort by all of the columns (including the sticky one) becomes rather convoluted and difficult.